# Isolate input after first default in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am working with dynamic UI and would like to choose the default of and input, **and** isolate the following values.

In the following example, I can isolate the default value (`value = isolate(input$dynamic))`, but I cannot set a default (different from the min).

Is there a way to do both (set value and isolate after)?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        fluidRow(
            textInput("label", "labelasd"),
            selectInput("type_of_pe", "Type of policy estimate", c("type 1", "type 2", "type 3")), 
            uiOutput("data_in")
        )
    )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$data_in <- renderUI({
        output <- tagList()
        output [[1]] <- sliderInput("dynamic", input$label, value = isolate(input$dynamic), min = 0, max = 100)
        output [[2]] <- sliderInput("dynamic", input$label, value = isolate(input$dynamic) * 20, min = 5, max = 20)
        if (input$type_of_pe == "type 1") {
            lapply( 1, function(x) output[[x]] )
        } else if (input$type_of_pe == "type 2") {
            lapply( 2, function(x) output[[x]] )
        } else if (input$type_of_pe == "type 3") {
            lapply( c(1,2), function(x) output[[x]] )
        }

    })
     }
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: please provide a full minimal example that can be run

Comment: The example above now runs in my machine. Let me know if you still cannot get it to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reactive value to specify whether to use the default value or the value from `input$dynamic`.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # initialize reactive value as TRUE
  use_default <- reactiveVal(T)
  # if slider is moved, stop using the default
  observeEvent(input$dynamic, ignoreInit=T, {
    use_default(F)
  })

  output$data_in <- renderUI({
    # check whether the value should use default or not (default is set to 10)
    value <- if (use_default()) 10 else isolate(input$dynamic)
    output <- tagList()
    output [[1]] <- sliderInput("dynamic", input$label, value = value, min = 0, max = 100)
    output [[2]] <- sliderInput("dynamic", input$label, value = value * 20, min = 5, max = 20)
    if (input$type_of_pe == "type 1") {
      lapply( 1, function(x) output[[x]] )
    } else if (input$type_of_pe == "type 2") {
      lapply( 2, function(x) output[[x]] )
    } else if (input$type_of_pe == "type 3") {
      lapply( c(1,2), function(x) output[[x]] )
    }

  })
}
```